# Saving DataSet<Row> as CSV

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to save the `DataSet<Row>` as CSV output? `toDataSet` API expects `Row.class` and `writeAsCSV` expects Tuple. Could you please help?

```
DataSet<Row> finalResult = tEnv.toDataSet(flattenedTripByGender, Row.class);
finalResult.writeAsCsv("../data/tripbygender.csv");
```

And this is an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.api.table.Row cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvOutputFormat.writeRecord(CsvOutputFormat.java:44)
```

Aruna

Answer (score 0):

You can directly emit a `Table` without converting it to a `DataSet` using a `TableSink`.

Flink 1.1.x comes with a `CsvTableSink` which is used as follow:

```
// compute your result
Table result = // ...

// create a TableSink
TableSink sink = new CsvTableSink("/path/to/file", fieldDelim = "|");
// write the result Table to the TableSink
result.writeToSink(sink);
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you should mark the answer accordingly.